# Replace SimpleFormController with annotations (spring < 3 to 4.3 conversion)

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to convert some code from Spring 2.* to 4.3.

How would I write the bellow code with annotations? I'm having trouble getting my head around the documentation.

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

public class SearchController extends SimpleFormController {

    public SearchController () {
        this.setFormView("edit-search");
        this.setSuccessView("edit-search");
        this.setCommandClass(ListWrapper.class);
        this.setCommandName("aList");
        this.setSessionForm(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do something similar like below :

```java
@Controller // instead of extending SimpleFormController
    @RequestMapping("/yourFile.htm")
    public class SearchController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST) // here I have added as Post as HTTP method as a sample. 
    public void SearchController(@ModelAttribute("aList")/* commandName */ ListWrapper listWrapper/*CommandClass*/){ 
    if(some Errors|| null validation fails){
    return "edit-search";// formView
    }
        return "edit-search";// successView
}


}
```